# How to access specific joint in usdz modelComponent

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am really having a hard time with this.. =(
When I export a simple example zylinder from blender to fxb or gltf, to convert it to usdz, everything works fine.
Adding the usdz to my project seems ok and looks like this:

[screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkYOD.png)

How can I access my joints?
The thing is, I cant get multiple animations to work in usdz and now I want to transform the joints ...

Printing out the jointTransforms and jointNames looks like so:

```
[
RealityKit.Transform(
    scale: SIMD3<Float>(1.0, 1.0000001, 1.0000001), 
    rotation: simd_quatf(real: 0.7071067, imag: SIMD3<Float>(-0.7071068, 0.0, 0.0)), 
    translation: SIMD3<Float>(0.0, -4.2632564e-13, 49.387093)), 

RealityKit.Transform(
    scale: SIMD3<Float>(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 
    rotation: simd_quatf(real: 1.0, imag: SIMD3<Float>(1.323489e-23, 0.0, 0.0)), 
    translation: SIMD3<Float>(0.0, 53.401974, 1.1857624e-14)), 

RealityKit.Transform(
    scale: SIMD3<Float>(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 
    rotation: simd_quatf(real: 1.0, imag: SIMD3<Float>(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), 
    translation: SIMD3<Float>(0.0, 54.57564, 1.211823e-14)), 

RealityKit.Transform(
    scale: SIMD3<Float>(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 
    rotation: simd_quatf(real: 1.0, imag: SIMD3<Float>(1.323489e-23, 0.0, 0.0)), 
    translation: SIMD3<Float>(0.0, 53.988808, 1.1987927e-14))]
```

["Joint_00", "Joint_00/Joint_01", "Joint_00/Joint_01/Joint_02", "Joint_00/Joint_01/Joint_02/Joint_03"]

But how can I access any of them?

I am kind of new to ARKit and RealityComposer, so maybe I am mixin up some stuff, .., sry...